# How to say "moon landing" in Latin?

Tags: word-request

In Romance languages, there is a single word used for "moon landing":

- Italian: Allunaggio
- Spanish: Alunizaje
- Portuguese: Alunissagem
- French: Alunissage
- etc.

What would be the Latin equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Lexicon recentis Latinitatis*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicon_Recentis_Latinitatis) from the Vatican's (late) *Latinitas* foundation, which mostly avoids neologisms, says *appulsus lunae*.

The *Lexicon auxiliare* (German-Latin) offers *delunatio*, though it does not appear to have caught on.

The *Lexicon recentis Latinitatis* is somewhat notorious for its cumbersome paraphrases, but *appulsus lunae* is clearly modeled after *appulsus terrae* and looks quite useable to me.

You might enjoy [this essay on the Apollo 11 mission](http://www.johnbyronkuhner.com/2021/02/libellus-memorialis-itineris-admirandi-apollis-undecimi/) by no lesser person than Reginald Foster, which does (as far as I can see) not offer a word for "moon landing," but a number of other interesting coinages such as *luninauta* or *scapha lunipeta*.

Comment: This is a perfect answer thank you